# Excel VBA To Close Add-In With No Prompt To Save

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am showing an add-in, copying a worksheet to the active workbook, then hiding the add-in again.  This works as it should, but the user gets a prompt asking if they want to save changes to the add-in when the Excel workbook is closed.  How can I modify this syntax so that the add-in will always be closed with no prompt to save changes?

```
Dim wbName As String
wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = False
Dim LookupWB As Workbook: Set LookupWB = Application.Workbooks("URZ.xlam")
Sheets("Green").Select
ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Workbooks(wbName).Sheets(1)
LookupWB.IsAddin = True
```

Comment: add this line: `LookupWB.Saved = true`

Comment: But i don't think you need to show the add-in and then hide it.

Comment: @Fadi - I am trying to modify a worksheet that exists in the add-in, and the only way to achieve this I discovered was to show the add-in, copy the worksheet to the current workbook, then hide the addin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this line: `LookupWB.Saved = True`
But i don't think you need to show the add-in and then hide it.

Try this code:

```
Sub test()

 Dim Wb As Workbook: Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
 Dim LookupWB As Workbook: Set LookupWB = Application.Workbooks("URZ.xlam")
 LookupWB.Sheets("Green").Copy Before:=Wb.Sheets(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  No need to show the add-in, I could just copy over the worksheet then delete when finished.